# navigation.navigate flickers to show nested navigator home

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

My ReactNavigation is nested as below on home of App;

```
<Root>
<Drawer>
   <DrawerScreen1/>
   <DrawerScreen2/>
   <StackNavigator Initial=StackScreen1>
       <StackScreen1/>
       <StackScreen2/>
       <StackScreen3/>
   </StackNavigator>
   <DrawerScreen3/>
</Drawer>
</Root>
```

**Problem:**
If I call `props.navigation.navigate(route)` from any DrawerScreen with a route which is directly inside the drawer container (like DrawerScreen2, DrawerScreen3), it works smoothly and quickly.

However, **from any Drawer Screen, if I call `props.navigation.navigate(route)` with any StackNavigator route (like StackScreen2 or StackScreen3), it flickers by showing StackScreen1 for a fraction of second and then goes to desired screen** which doesn't looks good. How can I avoid Stacknavigator's initialscreen to appear before redirection for smooth experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like below:

DrawerComponent:

```
<Drawer.Navigator>
   <DrawerScreen1/>
   <DrawerScreen2/>
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Navigation

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
   <Stack.Screen name="DashboardStack" component={DrawerComponent}/>
   <Stack.Screen name="StackScreen1" />
   <Stack.Screen name="StackScreen2" />
   <Stack.Screen name="StackScreen3" />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

You can navigate to any stack screen easily from the drawer.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks! However, `props.navigation.replace` stopped working when calling Stack Navigator Screen from Drawer Screen. So I had to replace the `replace()` with `navigate()`.